# Move from Activity to Fragment when button clicked

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I used this code to move from Activity to Fragment when button clicked but when I run this code I find Activity is still in background.

```
 TopicsFragment fragment = new TopicsFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.welcome_id, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to understand what Activity and Fragments are. You cannot move from Activity to Fragment.

You can inflate a Fragment or Fragments into an Activity. Fragments cannot be independent from an activity.

> A fragment must always be hosted in an activity and the fragment's
>   lifecycle is directly affected by the host activity's lifecycle. For
>   example, when the activity is paused, so are all fragments in it, and
>   when the activity is destroyed, so are all fragments. However, while
>   an activity is running (it is in the resumed lifecycle state), you can
>   manipulate each fragment independently, such as add or remove them.
>   When you perform such a fragment transaction, you can also add it to a
>   back stack that's managed by the activity—each back stack entry in the
>   activity is a record of the fragment transaction that occurred. The
>   back stack allows the user to reverse a fragment transaction (navigate
>   backwards), by pressing the Back button.

**Source:** https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to see the activity after entering into fragment, you could extend from `DialogFragment` and make it fullscreen, there are many examples, google it using "android fullscreen dialogfragment".

and [here is DialogFragment doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment).